# How to install packages of tcl in MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, tcl, package, tk-toolkit

I want install tserialports package on mac in tcl.I tried with below code. but not able to install it.

```
package ifneeded tserialport 1.1 \
    [list load [file join $dir libtserialport1.1.dylib] tserialport]
```

and run file on wish tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having trouble installing a package, you can use it in the same directory of your project. What you need to do is to append the folder of your library (the one that contains the **pkgIndex.sh**) file to the auto_path list on your code before the package requere command.

It would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

lappend ::auto_path /Users/ninguem/Dropbox/prg_new/tcltk/png_test/Img1.4.11

package require Tk
package require Img

image create photo icon -file "icon.png"
image create photo iconDisabled -file "icon.png" -format "png -alpha 0.5"
button .b -image icon
```

In this example, I don't have the Img package installed. So, the first thing I had to do was to add the line with `lappend ...` in the beginning of the code.

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tclkit), the Tcl interpreter will look for libraries on all the paths on this list.

I struggled a bit with that at first, but it turns out that using libraries in Tcl is pretty simple.